# Folding Array of hashes to HoH

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have `$maps` as AoH which I wish to make a `$new_map` to be a HoH based on a member of the enclosing hashes.

I currently have:

```
map { $new_map->{$_->{TYPE}} = $_; delete $_->{TYPE} } @$maps;
```

This does the job..

I wonder if there's a better/simpler/cleaner way to get the intent. Perhaps, by getting the return value from map?

```
$new_map = map { ... } @$maps;
```

Thanks

Comment: An example of your data would be a better gauge of the which way the data should be processed

Comment: Minor shortening: You should be able to change `$new_map->{$_->{TYPE}} = $_; delete $_->{TYPE}` to `$new_map->{delete $_->{TYPE}} = $_` since `delete` returns the value it deleted.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, somehow when I deleted from `$new_map` it was still there, I can't remember what it was... but really I will not need the old maps.. If you can help me just kind of in-edit-replace :) on $maps that would suffice

Comment: FYI, I take the idea from [here](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#KeyAttr_=%3E_{_list_}_#_in+out_-_important) HTH

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: The values of the hash referenced by `$new_map` are the same as the values of the array referenced by `$maps`. Removing `$new_map->{foo}{TYPE}` will also remove `$maps->[0]{TYPE}` because only the reference has been copied, so it doesn't matter where the `TYPE` field is removed from

Comment: @Borodin Ah, that's right, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original solution is a misuse of `map` as it doesn't use the list that the operator returns. `for` is the correct tool here, and I think it reads much better that way too, especially if you use the fact that `delete` returns the value of the element it has removed

```
$new_map->{ delete $_->{TYPE} } = $_ for @$maps;
```

Or you could translate the array using `map` properly, as here

```
my %new_map = map { delete $_->{TYPE} => $_ } @$maps;
```

The choice is your own

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, I did feel I some misuse but could not pinpoint just what is was. You hit the nail right on the head!

Comment: I was (and still am a little) struggling to understand how does map return a hash here?

Comment: @lzc: You can defined a hash by assigning a flat list of key/value pairs. The block of `map` is executed in list context, and here it provides one such pair `delete $_->{TYPE} => $_ `for each element of `@$map`. By the way, if you really need a new hash reference, then I think I would prefer to see a plain hash built like this and the reference taken afterwards, rather than wrapping the entire `map` inside an anonymous hash constructor

Answer (score 1):

Using map in void context obfuscates the intent, and altering original `@$maps` may not be a good idea (map with side effects?), thus

```
my $new_map = {
  map { my %h = %$_; delete $h{TYPE} => \%h } @$maps
};
```

Comment: I like your idea of making new_map a href but my I think this is the best way: `$new_map = {map { delete $_->{TYPE} => $_ } @$maps }`

Comment: It's worth pointing out that your solution doesn't remove the `TYPE` element from the original hashes

Comment: `altering original @$maps may not be a good idea` covers that.